# How to change table background onmouseover?

Tags: javascript, html, mouseover

I have tabs one says 'Search' and the other says 'Tags'

Search is the default tab so it has a grey rounded edge table background while 'Tags' has a white rounded edge background.

I want to be able to put the mouse over 'Tags' and the background to change from white to grey. How is this done?

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="roundedcornr_box_407494">
<div class="roundedcornr_top_407494"><div></div></div>
<div class="roundedcornr_content_407494">
     <font color="#ffffff" size="2" face="helvetica">
 Search
</font>  
  </div>
<div class="roundedcornr_bottom_407494"><div></div></div>
</div>

</td>
</tr>
</table>

 </td>
<td>
<div style="margin-left:10px;" />
<center>
<table height="20" width="30" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>
<center>
<div class="roundedcornr_box_235759">
<div class="roundedcornr_top_235759"><div></div></div>
    <div class="roundedcornr_content_235759">
<font color="#585858" size="2" face="helvetica">
   Tags
</font>      </div>
 <div class="roundedcornr_bottom_235759"><div></div></div>
</div>
</center>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
.roundedcornr_box_407494 {
 background: #bdbdbd;
}
.roundedcornr_top_407494 div {
 background: url(roundedcornr_407494_tl.png) no-repeat top left;
}
.roundedcornr_top_407494 {
background: url(roundedcornr_407494_tr.png) no-repeat top right;
}
.roundedcornr_bottom_407494 div {
background: url(roundedcornr_407494_bl.png) no-repeat bottom left;
}
.roundedcornr_bottom_407494 {
background: url(roundedcornr_407494_br.png) no-repeat bottom right;
 }

.roundedcornr_top_407494 div, .roundedcornr_top_407494, 
.roundedcornr_bottom_407494 div, .roundedcornr_bottom_407494 {
 width: 100%;
  height: 5px;
 font-size: 1px;
 }
.roundedcornr_content_407494 { margin: 0 5px; }
```

Thanks!

James

Comment: first of all improve your html where are the starting tags of the table you are closing below the div **class="roundedcornr_bottom_407494**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With :hover.

Sample:
http://jsfiddle.net/stKn3/

Answer (score 0):

With Css

```
table:hover
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

or

```
table tr:hover
{
    background-color:gray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its better to have a single images as background(with corners #as you trying to do) of the tabs And changing the background image on mouseover event. Instead of splitting them and merging the pieces together again by div tags.

Follow these examples :

http://www.codefoot.com/javascript/script_image_textarea_mouseover.html

http://www.codebelly.com/javascript/backimagechange.html

Comment: Thanks for the help so far! I did consider this but the images were so blurry and it looks so much better by using the corner images. Is there really no way to do it this way?

Comment: I found your approach a difficult one. i cannot say there is no way to do it that way. but there are really other easy ways too.

Comment: @James, are you forgetting accepting and upvoting the answer ? i gave you 2 correct answers

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<TR onMouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE'"onMouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">
     <td>Some data</td>
</TR>
```

OR

```
<table onMouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEEEE'" onMouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">

</table>
```

EDIT:

Try this complete HTML.

```
<html>
<body>
<table >
    <tr onMouseover="this.bgColor='#EEEE00'" onMouseout="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'">
        <td>
        Some Data on table's first row
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

It needs some modifications to use on your code. Try it on your own.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, I tried it but nothing happened. Because its not a standard table bgcolor its a rounded corner box that is in the table that i want to change color. How is that done?

Comment: i added the complete HTML. its your job to modify your code. i just gave you an idea.

Comment: But because its not table background i want to change its the rounded edge box IN the table I dont get how to write the code. Because the rounded edge box isnt an image i cant use onmouseover="image.jpg" so how do I include the div tags with onmouseover?

Comment: @epascarello thanks for reminding me that the bgcolor attribute is deprecated. But it is still supported in all major browsers. So there will be no problem.

Comment: @James I think there is problem with your CSS. But you haven't posted it.

Comment: @gt_ebuddy I have edited my question and posted my CSS, please check it out!

Comment: Basically, the css i put up is for the round edge box in the 'Search' table and its exactly the same for the 'Tag' round edge box css just with a different colour (white). So all I want to do is have the 'Search' round edge css apply to the 'Tag' tab when i put my mouseover the 'Tag' tab